# Hiding document changed message for name picker after enabling enableModifiedFlag property

Tags: xpages

I have a enabled this property on the form. The form has various fields along with few name pickers. When I click the Name picker I get the document changed message. How can I stop this message for Name pickers?

Comment: I only see this in IE. is that the same for you?

Comment: Yes Henrik..You are right it shows this in IE. Works perfectly in  FF and Chrome. Unfortunately our corporate browser is IE :(. Any workarounds?

Comment: I have not found it, unfortunately. Actually, in one app I have disabled the modifiedFlag if browser is IE and replaced it with a warning message

Answer (score 1):

This issue fixed in Domino 9.0 - and should be present in the Public Beta of 9.0 published before Christmas 2012.
Also, this fix should also be available in the Extension Library releases post November 2012.

If it is not working for you let me know.

Answer (score 0):

We recently upgraded to Ext. Lib version 8.5.3.20130315-0724 (4 Apr 2013). But still enableModifiedFlag does not work in **IE**. I have tried to describe steps below :

1. Open Xpage with enableModifiedProperty set to "true".
2. Update any input field.
3. Select name from value picker.
4. Press "X" on selected value. Boom...it shows "Do you want to move away from this page" dialog.

I checked in FireFox. It works as expected.

Cheers,
Ravi