# xPages Extension Library name picker with modified flag enabled on page

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using Domino 8.5.2 and the Extension Library for xpages. I have enabled the modified flag on the page and run into errors on IE8. When I load the page in IE8, modify another field, then attempt to use the name picker control I get an IE error that the browser thinks I am about to open another page not saving the data"are you sure you want to navigate away from the page, blah blah blah". Am I missing something here, or is the modified flag not respected by the extension library?

Comment: Its possible that I found an answer... unfortunately... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468739/hiding-document-changed-message-for-name-picker-after-enabling-enablemodifiedfla but if anyone can offer a suggestion on a work around to not using the modified flag I am all ears.

Comment: in comment link Paul suggests to use newer ExtLib - it seems you did not upgraded for some time :-) try to use most recent version of ExtLib, folks at IBM update it quite regularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the duplicate post suggests: update to Domino 9.0 which is available in a few days (March 21).

For XPages in general I will suggest you upgrade from 8.5.2 anyway since 8.5.3 and 9.0 contains many improvements for XPages.

Comment: I will be moving to Domino 9, but won't be doing so for a bit. Trust me I want those improvements.